# What would be the proper way to update animation values in a Flutter animation?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter, flutter-animation

So I'm trying to create an animation in Flutter that requires a different outcome every time the user presses a button.

I've implemented the following code according to the [Flutter Animations tutorial](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) and created a function to update it.

```
class _RoulettePageWidgetState extends State<RoulettePageWidget>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
   Animation<double> _animation;
   Tween<double> _tween;
   AnimationController _animationController;

   int position = 0;

   @override
   void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _animationController =
          AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
      _tween = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 100.0);
      _animation = _tween.animate(_animationController)
          ..addListener(() {
              setState(() {});
          });
   }

   void setNewPosition(int newPosition) {
      _tween = Tween(
        begin: 0.0,
        end: math.pi*2/25*newPosition);
      _animationController.reset();
      _tween.animate(_animationController);
      _animationController.forward();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
         child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
               Center(
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                     angle: _animationController.value,
                     child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_upward,
                     size: 250.0,
                  ),
               )),
               Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
               ),
               RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('SPIN'),
                  onPressed: () {
                     setState(() {
                        setNewPosition(math.Random().nextInt(25));
                     });
                  },
               )
            ],
         )
      );
   }
}
```

As you can see I'm updating the `_tween`'s `begin:` and `end:` but this doesn't seem to change the animation.

So what should I be doing to create a 'different' animation every time the users presses the button?

The general idea is to make the animations build upon each other with a random new value so for example:

- first spin: 0 -> 10
- second spin: 10 -> 13
- third spin: 13 -> 18
- ... etc

So I wondered if I could update the animation, or should I create a new animation every time?
Another thing I could think of was tracking the positions and use the same animation every time (0.0 -> 100.0) to act as a percentage of the transfer.

So instead of creating a new animation from 10 -> 15 I would be doing something like:
`currentValue = 10 + (15-10)/100*_animationController.value`

Comment: could you also share your setNewPosition call?

Comment: I mean your build method would be really useful because right now, I feel what you are asking as a bit abstract.

Comment: I've added the build implementation.

Comment: It does reset the animation and it's also playing again but with the initial values and not the new once.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm going to skip your code a bit, and focus on what you're really asking:

> The general idea is to make the animations build upon each other with a random new value so for example:
>
> - first spin: 0 -> 10
> - second spin: 10 -> 13
> - third spin: 13 -> 18
> - ... etc

With an explicit animation like this, there are three objects you are interested in:

- a *controller*, which is a special kind of Animation that simply generates values linearly from its lower to its upper bound (both doubles, typically 0.0 and 1.0). You can control the flow of the animation - send it running forward, reverse it, stop it, or reset it.
- a *tween*, which *isn't* an Animation but rather an *Animatable*. A tween defines the interpolation between two values, which don't even have to be numbers. It implements a `transform` method under the hood that takes in the current value of an animation and spits out the actual value you want to work with: another number, a color, a linear gradient, even a whole widget. This is what you should use to generate your angles of rotation.
- an *animation*, which is the animation whose value you're actually going to work with (so this is where you'd grab values to build with). You get this by giving your tween a parent Animation to transform - this might be your controller directly but can also be some other sort of animation you've built on it (like a CurvedAnimation, which would give you easing or bouncy/elastic curves and so on). Flutter's animations are highly composable that way.

Your code is failing largely because you're not actually using the top-level animation you created in your build method *and* you're creating a new tween and animation every time you call `setNewPosition`. You can use the same tween and animation for multiple animation "cycles" - simply change the `begin` and `end` properties of the existing tween and it bubbles up to the animation. That ends up something like this:

```
class _RoulettePageWidgetState extends State<RoulettePageWidget>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
   Animation<double> _animation;
   Tween<double> _tween;
   AnimationController _animationController;
   math.Random _random = math.Random();

   int position = 0;

   double getRandomAngle() {
      return math.pi * 2 / 25 * _random.nextInt(25);
   }

   @override
   void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _animationController =
          AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
      _tween = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: getRandomAngle());
      _animation = _tween.animate(_animationController)
          ..addListener(() {
              setState(() {});
          });
   }

   void setNewPosition() {
      _tween.begin = _tween.end;
      _animationController.reset();
      _tween.end = getRandomAngle();
      _animationController.forward();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
         child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
               Center(
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                     angle: _animation.value,
                     child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_upward,
                     size: 250.0,
                  ),
               )),
               Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
               ),
               RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('SPIN'),
                  onPressed: setNewPosition,
               )
            ],
         )
      );
   }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not only does this answer my question but your explanation really helps me to understand the whole concept. Funny thing is that I basically had this before I tried creating a new `Tween` except for reading out the right animation object!

Comment: You're welcome! Also you should look into the `AnimatedBuilder` widget once you've got a good grasp of how Flutter handles animations :)

Comment: I will! I saw all kinds of interesting Widgets to experiment with.

Answer (score 6):

While working, in no situation will you actually want to make these animations *within* your layout as explained by @filleduchaos.

This is under optimized, as you're rebuilding far more than you should for the animation. And it's a pain to write yourself.

You'll want to use the `AnimatedWidget` family for this. They are divided into two 
kinds:

- XXTransition
- AnimatedXX

The first is a low layer that consumes an `Animation` and listens to it so that you don't need to do that ugly :

```
..addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});
```

The second handles the remaining pieces: `AnimationController`, `TickerProvider` and `Tween`.

This makes using animations *much* easier as it's almost entirely automatical.

In your case a rotation example would be as followed:

```
class RotationExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const RotationExample({
    Key key,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  RotationExampleState createState() {
    return new RotationExampleState();
  }
}

class RotationExampleState extends State<RotationExample> {
  final _random = math.Random();
  double rad = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _rotate,
      child: AnimatedTransform(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(rad),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 42.0,
          width: 42.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _rotate() {
    setState(() {
      rad = math.pi * 2 / 25 * _random.nextInt(25);
    });
  }
}
```

Easier right?

The irony is that Flutter forgot to provide an `AnimatedTransform` (even although we have many others !). But no worries, I made it for you!

The `AnimatedTransform` implementation is as followed :

```
class AnimatedTransform extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget {
  final Matrix4 transform;
  final AlignmentGeometry alignment;
  final bool transformHitTests;
  final Offset origin;
  final Widget child;

  const AnimatedTransform({
    Key key,
    @required this.transform,
    @required Duration duration,
    this.alignment,
    this.transformHitTests = true,
    this.origin,
    this.child,
    Curve curve = Curves.linear,
  })  : assert(transform != null),
        assert(duration != null),
        super(
          key: key,
          duration: duration,
          curve: curve,
        );

  @override
  _AnimatedTransformState createState() => _AnimatedTransformState();
}

class _AnimatedTransformState
    extends AnimatedWidgetBaseState<AnimatedTransform> {
  Matrix4Tween _transform;

  @override
  void forEachTween(TweenVisitor<dynamic> visitor) {
    _transform = visitor(_transform, widget.transform,
        (dynamic value) => Matrix4Tween(begin: value));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform(
      alignment: widget.alignment,
      transform: _transform.evaluate(animation),
      transformHitTests: widget.transformHitTests,
      origin: widget.origin,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

I will submit a pull request so that in the future you won't need this bit of code.

Comment: Eh, they're clearly working on understanding *explicit* animations. You don't always want widgets to implicitly animate themselves, and it's better to figure out how the Animation/Animatable stack works with something as easy as doubles.

Comment: But in production, this is what you'd want to use instead of the previous code. The fact that he's learning doesn't justify a partial answer.

Comment: They're following an official tutorial that's explicitly about explicit animations and asked for help with that. I don't see how explaining why they're stuck on their tutorial about explicit animations is a partial answer.

Comment: There literally is the rest of the tutorial right there, which also touches on AnimatedWidget and AnimatedBuilder.

Comment: He's not following the tutorial, he's using it as a reference for his own project. But this doesn't matter anyway, the purpose of StackOverflow is to provide helpful answers for the whole world to see. If this helps, then it's fine.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I appreciate your answer. Do I understand that with "This is under optimized, as you're rebuilding far more than you should for the animation." the fact that every set state now also draws the whole layout instead of just the `Image`? It's true that I'm still learning and practicing how and where to use state.
I will look into the animation related widgets.

Comment: Also, I was following the tutorial and tried to use it to see if I understand correctly. There I missed the explanation of how to change the values, hence my question.
Because @filleduchaos answered that specific question I marked that as the answer.

Comment: You're not rebuilding just the `Image`. You actually rebuild everything inside `_RoulettePageWidgetState`, including the button and all the other widgets. With the code I provided the animation rebuild _only_ the transform, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse your animation with a different path (go/back way). Try this.

In your `setNewPosition` function, just define new `begin/end` value for `_tween`.

```
   void setNewPosition() {
      _tween.begin = 0; //new begin int value
      _tween.end = 1; //new end int value
      _animationController.reverse();
   }
```